# TscToolPath null in Microsoft.TypeScript.targets after installed update 3 of visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript, tsc

I get this error in visual studio 2015 after installing update 3. Using TS 2.0.

```
Error       Invalid command line switch for "tsc.exe". Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1   ProjectTest C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets 214
```

This points to this code so i think TscToolPath is null

```
 <VsTsc
      ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
      ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
      TSConfigFile="%(ConfigFiles.Identity)"
      YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
      ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"
      ToolsVersion="$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)"
      TypeScriptCompileBlocked="$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)"
      ComputeOutputOnly="false">

      <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedJavascript" ItemName="emittedFiles" />
  </VsTsc>
```

I can't find that TscToolPath value anywhere. I have this in Microsoft.Typescript.Default.props

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>false</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>false</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>true</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

My TS config in .iceproj (telerik appbuilder)

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>False</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>False</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Added this to iceproj but didn't fix.

```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Please help :)

Comment: have you found a fix to this yet? Their support tends be quick fast. I also have the same problem with typescript 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the same steps work for v2 of TypeScript for you (I'm still using 1.8), but the same error while trying to run the project.

So how did I fix it... (it's possibly OK to skip to part 4, not certain after all my changes)

**Part 1.**

Ensure the TypeScript options are set in Visual Studio. 
[image: TypeScript options]

**Part 2.**

Add a tsconfig.json file.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "platforms"
  ]
}
```

**Part 3.**

I ended up getting rid of all my current typing files from nuget and slowly replaced them all using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings#references). Mostly due to errors returned in part 4. Rxjs being one of the ringleaders to my problems.

**Part 4.**

run `tsc` from the command prompt. This will reveal any errors with your files. Basically, AppBuilder did use to continue with errors but for some reason, at the moment it is not building without errors. Something as simple as `typings/globals/cordova-ionic/index.d.ts(4,12): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Ionic'.` will cause it to fail but then getting a few more typescript definitions fixes it:
`typings install dt~cordova-ionic/plugins/keyboard --global --save`

**Part 5.**

When there are finally no more errors returned by `tsc` try to run appbuilder from Visual Studio again. This time, the Device Simulator came up.

Hopefully, those steps fix your problems as well. Good Luck. Any additional from tsc then add them to your question if you cant work them out.

**TypeScript 2 update**

I've installed [TypeScript 2 RC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/) and it seems to run from that automatically (without changing the project file). Building or running the project the output gives: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.0\tsc.exe --project "H:\WhatsMyScore1\WhatsMyScore\MobileProject1\tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles