# Cordova/Ionic project typescript compile error

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have this Cordova/Ionic project in Visual Studio 2017 and after some recent changes to add speech to text funcionality, I'm failing to build the project after cloning it to another machine.

The project structure is something like this:

[project structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZMax.jpg)
[project structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuse8.jpg)

When I build the solution, I get this error:

> Invalid command line switch for "tsc.exe". Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

And, much probably because of this first error, I get hundreds of errors like these:

> Cannot write file 'D:/NT4-PROJECTS/ionicSenhas/www/libs/pre-cordova.js' because it would overwrite input file.
>
> Cannot write file 'D:/NT4-PROJECTS/ionicSenhas/www/libs/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js' because it would overwrite input file.

Searching for an answer for this

> *Invalid command line "switch for "tsc.exe".* Value cannot be null." Parameter name: path1

problem, I found I few suggestions, like this:

[TscToolPath null in Microsoft.TypeScript.targets after installed update 3 of visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039055/tsctoolpath-null-in-microsoft-typescript-targets-after-installed-update-3-of-vis)

and here I have a doubt: **is it mandatory to have a tsconfig file for the tsc.exe to compile the typescript files?**
I'm asking this because the project I cloned from the repository does not have this tsconfig.json file - I'm not sure if the programmer who did this commit
forgot to add this file, or if I really can have typescript files in a project without the tsconfig file.

Anyway, I tried this suggestion and added the tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "platforms"
   ]
}
```

but the problem remains;

> Cannot write file 'D:/NT4-PROJECTS/ionicSenhas/lib/angular-i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js' because it would overwrite input file

I have tried so many things(update dependencies, uninstall and install again), I guess this is the kind of thing really hard for anyone to figure it out 
without looking at my environment.

Comment: I am also having this issue.  I am opening a legacy Ionic 1 project for the first time in VS2017.  Ionic 1 is based on AngularJS and not Angular (no TypeScript...).  Also today, my VS2017 updated to 15.5.6 (not sure if that has something to do with it).  Very confused about this error.

Comment: I have also tried a new Cordova template project in VS2017 and run it and the same error occurs...

Comment: @nokturnal, it much probably has something to do with this update, but even with that information, I couldn't find an workaround. There's a few suggestions here - let me know if it was helpful.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209035/apache-cordova-tools-error-after-upgrading-to-vs-2.html?inRegister=true

Comment: Yesterday was strange.  The yellow update icon displayed for the 15.6  then hid itself randomly during the day.

Comment: Adding the tsconfig file worked for me. (I also did a new install of VS2017)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do a repair on the VS2017 install. After that the TSC error was gone. I tested by creating a new default VS Cordova project and building that. Also, after the repair I had gone from VS2017 15.5.6 to 15.6.1... Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Creating a blank cordova app in vs2017 and then copying the contents of the newly created .jsproj file to my original project file worked for me.